# Post Build Script

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, projects-and-solutions, csproj, solution

I using *VS2017* for my solution.

I have a main repository in bitbucket (say directory name is **A**) and few dependencies in the form of Subtree (this is inside **A** folder and other subfolder say **B**).

I want to add a *post build* in all Subtree (project inside **B**) such that if the subtree project is present under a folder **A** (in this case) then copy the dll from **B's** bin folder to a folder in **A**. But this script should not run if subtree project in master directory.

So resolve I wanted to find out the parent directory of folder **B**. If this parent direct is **A** then only copy dll from **B**/din/*.dll to **A**/Assembles/bin/*.dll

How can I find out of **B's** parent folder is **A** in post build script in VS2017

Comment: Why you don't set the `OutputPath` variable, or use `projectReference`? What is your main goal?

Comment: Basically, I am shifting source control from SVN to bitbucket. We have one .NET solution (Say A) and have multiple sub module (say B and C). While moving to bitbucket, each of Solution A, B and C become a separate repository but Solution B and C become sub-tree. So if a developer changes B or C from subtree then I want to copy the dll from B/bin folder to A/Assembless/ folder.. But if developer tried to build master repository of B then this copying of dll is not required. To achive it I have written post build script to copy dlls but this copying is conditional.

Comment: I want to put an IF condition in post build script such that if solution B is contained under a folder A then only run the script otherwise not. How can I achieve conditional execution of post build script

Comment: Do you mean `$(solutionDir)` variable from `msbuild`?

Comment: When I use $(solutionDir) in sub-tree project (not in the main project) then it gives me complete path "C:\somefolder\A\B\" ... But instead I want to check whether the parent of B is A if yes then execute copy dll script. To do I need to get parent folder of $(solutionDir) and then compare if it is "A". This comparison will tell me there solution B is being used as sub-project for the mail project..Can we achieve it ?

Comment: In fact, I still do not understand what you're trying to try, and I think something's wrong here.

Comment: And also I think you are not careful about the difference between Solution (`.sln` file) and Project (`.csproj` file).

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue?If Baruch's answer is helpful and solved this issue please consider marking it as "accepted answer" to your question. If the issue persists, please feel free to contact us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Run post-build event in condition

So, you want to run a `PostBuild` event only in a specific case. For achieve that, you may use [`Condition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-element-msbuild).

In your `Condition`, you want to check the **parent** folder of your *Solution* or *Project* dir (honestly, I'm not sure what you meant).

#### MSBuild get the parent of dir

How you can get the parent dir?

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectParentDir>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(ProjectDir))))</ProjectParentDir>
    <SolutionParentDir>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(SolutionDir)))</SolutionParentDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

### Answer

So, now you can combine the above knowledge:

```xml
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="$(ProjectParentDir.EndsWith('A'))">
    // Do your post build
</Target>
```

#### Comment

Because I think that maybe your question is wrong, and maybe you can achieve your solution without `PostBuild`, I think you may use the tool I described to control the `OutputPath` itself.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectParentDir>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(ProjectDir))))</ProjectParentDir>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="$(ProjectParentDir.EndsWith('A'))">
    <OutputPath>Path/to/somewhere</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="!$(ProjectParentDir.EndsWith('A'))">
    <OutputPath>Path/to/somewhere</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

#### Read More

I'm not sure my syntax is correct, please read more:

- [Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions)
- [Property-Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions)